# App crashes on iOS 8 with crash log, what to read from that log

Tags: ios, crash, ios8

When I install through `Xcode` my app it all works good, after downloading it from App Store the first few times it works also good, but after few hours trying to launch the app it crashes on start.

Here is the log from one of the devices, What interesting info I can get from it?

```
Incident Identifier: 37F75352-D7E6-4EAB-B1B8-42144E40DE4F
CrashReporter Key:   3b5b7bee21090e6dbda917beb30594ae43084caf
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Process:             trappplus [724]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/99B7BB89-8587-4860-BB4D-C07B88ACDA53/trappplus.app/trappplus
Identifier:          com.trr.trrapp
Version:             4.0.0 (4.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-09-21 10:45:57.958 +0300
Launch Time:         2014-09-21 10:45:57.366 +0300
OS Version:          iOS 8.0 (12A365)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x23e20e3f 0x23d1b000 + 1072703
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x314fcc8b 0x314f6000 + 27787
2   CoreFoundation                  0x23e26189 0x23d1b000 + 1094025
3   CoreFoundation                  0x23e240a7 0x23d1b000 + 1085607
4   CoreFoundation                  0x23d56208 0x23d1b000 + 242184
5   trappplus                               0x000f9dc7 0xe7000 + 77255
6   UIKit                           0x27337545 0x272af000 + 558405
7   UIKit                           0x27526e69 0x272af000 + 2588265
8   UIKit                           0x2751ebdd 0x272af000 + 2554845
9   FrontBoardServices              0x2a5210e9 0x2a50c000 + 86249
10  CoreFoundation                  0x23de75b5 0x23d1b000 + 837045
11  CoreFoundation                  0x23de6879 0x23d1b000 + 833657
12  CoreFoundation                  0x23de5017 0x23d1b000 + 827415
13  CoreFoundation                  0x23d33621 0x23d1b000 + 99873
14  CoreFoundation                  0x23d33433 0x23d1b000 + 99379
15  GraphicsServices                0x2b0a10a9 0x2b098000 + 37033
16  UIKit                           0x2731d809 0x272af000 + 452617
17  trappplus                               0x000eb9e7 0xe7000 + 18919
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x31a7caaf 0x31a7b000 + 6831


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b42dfc 0x31b2e000 + 85500
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bc0d33 0x31bbd000 + 15667
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31ae2905 0x31a98000 + 305413
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30e1f9c5 0x30e1f000 + 2501
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30e3966d 0x30e1f000 + 108141
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x314fcf23 0x314f6000 + 28451
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30e36de1 0x30e1f000 + 97761
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30e368ab 0x30e1f000 + 96427
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x314fcdcf 0x314f6000 + 28111
9   CoreFoundation                  0x23d336b9 0x23d1b000 + 100025
10  CoreFoundation                  0x23d3342f 0x23d1b000 + 99375
11  GraphicsServices                0x2b0a10a5 0x2b098000 + 37029
12  UIKit                           0x2731d805 0x272af000 + 452613
13  trappplus                               0x000eb9e3 0xe7000 + 18915
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x31a7caad 0x31a7b000 + 6829

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b2f2a0 0x31b2e000 + 4768
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x31a689fd 0x31a5b000 + 55805
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x31a5e31f 0x31a5b000 + 13087

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b439cc 0x31b2e000 + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdea9 0x31bbd000 + 3753
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdb80 0x31bbd000 + 2944

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b439cc 0x31b2e000 + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdea9 0x31bbd000 + 3753
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdb80 0x31bbd000 + 2944

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b439cc 0x31b2e000 + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdea9 0x31bbd000 + 3753
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdb80 0x31bbd000 + 2944

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b439cc 0x31b2e000 + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdea9 0x31bbd000 + 3753
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdb80 0x31bbd000 + 2944

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b2f4f0 0x31b2e000 + 5360
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b2f2e5 0x31b2e000 + 4837
2   CoreFoundation                  0x23de6b4f 0x23d1b000 + 834383
3   CoreFoundation                  0x23de50f5 0x23d1b000 + 827637
4   CoreFoundation                  0x23d3361d 0x23d1b000 + 99869
5   CoreFoundation                  0x23d3342f 0x23d1b000 + 99375
6   CFNetwork                       0x238ec3db 0x23870000 + 508891
7   Foundation                      0x24b30387 0x24a5f000 + 856967
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbfe91 0x31bbd000 + 11921
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbfe03 0x31bbd000 + 11779
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdb8c 0x31bbd000 + 2956

Thread 7 name:  WebThread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b42ba8 0x31b2e000 + 84904
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbe047 0x31bbd000 + 4167
2   WebCore                         0x2f05bc85 0x2efd7000 + 543877
3   WebCore                         0x2f07044f 0x2efd7000 + 627791
4   WebKitLegacy                    0x2fb5efdd 0x2fb5b000 + 16349
5   WebKitLegacy                    0x2fb60d1b 0x2fb5b000 + 23835
6   WebCore                         0x2f024d59 0x2efd7000 + 318809
7   WebCore                         0x2f024be9 0x2efd7000 + 318441
8   WebCore                         0x2f06dcd3 0x2efd7000 + 617683
9   WebCore                         0x2f09b5b1 0x2efd7000 + 804273
10  WebCore                         0x2f09ae21 0x2efd7000 + 802337
11  CFNetwork                       0x23893ce9 0x23870000 + 146665
12  CFNetwork                       0x2392ff93 0x23870000 + 786323
13  CFNetwork                       0x23884beb 0x23870000 + 84971
14  CoreFoundation                  0x23d3308b 0x23d1b000 + 98443
15  CFNetwork                       0x23884aa3 0x23870000 + 84643
16  CFNetwork                       0x2388496b 0x23870000 + 84331
17  CFNetwork                       0x238847fd 0x23870000 + 83965
18  CoreFoundation                  0x23de758d 0x23d1b000 + 837005
19  CoreFoundation                  0x23de699b 0x23d1b000 + 833947
20  CoreFoundation                  0x23de5001 0x23d1b000 + 827393
21  CoreFoundation                  0x23d3361d 0x23d1b000 + 99869
22  CoreFoundation                  0x23d3342f 0x23d1b000 + 99375
23  WebCore                         0x2f05a9b7 0x2efd7000 + 539063
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbfe91 0x31bbd000 + 11921
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbfe03 0x31bbd000 + 11779
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdb8c 0x31bbd000 + 2956

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b439cc 0x31b2e000 + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdea9 0x31bbd000 + 3753
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdb80 0x31bbd000 + 2944

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b2f4f0 0x31b2e000 + 5360
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b2f2e5 0x31b2e000 + 4837
2   CoreFoundation                  0x23de6b4f 0x23d1b000 + 834383
3   CoreFoundation                  0x23de50f5 0x23d1b000 + 827637
4   CoreFoundation                  0x23d3361d 0x23d1b000 + 99869
5   CoreFoundation                  0x23d7c287 0x23d1b000 + 397959
6   CoreMotion                      0x24634def 0x245f6000 + 257519
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbfe91 0x31bbd000 + 11921
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbfe03 0x31bbd000 + 11779
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdb8c 0x31bbd000 + 2956

Thread 10 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b42b38 0x31b2e000 + 84792
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbf3f5 0x31bbd000 + 9205
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bc0319 0x31bbd000 + 13081
3   libc++.1.dylib                  0x30dd9f5b 0x30dd4000 + 24411
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x25115581 0x24fda000 + 1291649
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x24fef0eb 0x24fda000 + 86251
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x24feb605 0x24fda000 + 71173
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbfe91 0x31bbd000 + 11921
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbfe03 0x31bbd000 + 11779
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdb8c 0x31bbd000 + 2956

Thread 11 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b42b38 0x31b2e000 + 84792
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbf3f5 0x31bbd000 + 9205
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bc02d9 0x31bbd000 + 13017
3   libc++.1.dylib                  0x30dd9e8d 0x30dd4000 + 24205
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x251b6d21 0x24fda000 + 1953057
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x251b6d85 0x24fda000 + 1953157
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x24feb605 0x24fda000 + 71173
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbfe91 0x31bbd000 + 11921
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbfe03 0x31bbd000 + 11779
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdb8c 0x31bbd000 + 2956

Thread 12 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b2f4f0 0x31b2e000 + 5360
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b2f2e5 0x31b2e000 + 4837
2   CoreFoundation                  0x23de6b4f 0x23d1b000 + 834383
3   CoreFoundation                  0x23de50f5 0x23d1b000 + 827637
4   CoreFoundation                  0x23d3361d 0x23d1b000 + 99869
5   CoreFoundation                  0x23d3342f 0x23d1b000 + 99375
6   WebCore                         0x2f084029 0x2efd7000 + 708649
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x24feb605 0x24fda000 + 71173
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbfe91 0x31bbd000 + 11921
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbfe03 0x31bbd000 + 11779
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31bbdb8c 0x31bbd000 + 2956

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000003
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x33f699dc      r6: 0x33f55840      r7: 0x0024b428
    r8: 0x16566dd0    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x33f54074     r11: 0x16566df4
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x0024b41c      lr: 0x31bc0d37      pc: 0x31b42dfc
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0xe7000 - 0x132fff trappplus armv7  <083f21c49d69317ab797163c4cd456f3> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/99B7BB89-8587-4860-BB4D-C07B88ACDA53/trappplus.app/trappplus
0x1fe2c000 - 0x1fe4ffff dyld armv7s  <fd3fef9c43c9382e8e46d5d59fb52f86> /usr/lib/dyld
0x22740000 - 0x2282dfff RawCamera armv7s  <f36804b4286b392b9adefc60e5e1aa78> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x2283f000 - 0x228b1fff AGXGLDriver armv7s  <10c1b2150e3c3355973c87cd67726857> /System/Library/Extensions/AGXGLDriver.bundle/AGXGLDriver
0x228bf000 - 0x22a2bfff AVFoundation armv7s  <291c7a621b65396491697e7a7f728b16> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x22a2c000 - 0x22a8afff libAVFAudio.dylib armv7s  <1b452a7a75513cf9aa82e59feb7eef33> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x22ac4000 - 0x22ac4fff Accelerate armv7s  <3b40c742a7323214a5eb836630536bd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x22ad5000 - 0x22cf0fff vImage armv7s  <844c5a129a2f3dbe9c0b23824f3254f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x22cf1000 - 0x22dd7fff libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <aaaefc0f51f23049871f65ea9c4c7151> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x22dd8000 - 0x2309cfff libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <ba74aac653423b3b9bae4122d84935d8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x2309d000 - 0x230aefff libLinearAlgebra.dylib armv7s  <3df96b6a86303adea6abea68b7b610ac> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x230af000 - 0x2312bfff libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <fb3e0b030cc5346c89af71af2d17bc27> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x2312c000 - 0x2313efff libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <abd4670b295c3f50a2658d0f3f86d78c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x2313f000 - 0x2313ffff vecLib armv7s  <9495c9829e28344fb1820d2140fcaf35> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x23140000 - 0x23166fff Accounts armv7s  <cf7ceabb9af233f0b657f23423988703> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x23168000 - 0x231d8fff AddressBook armv7s  <eeeabdf6b9703b4f846b672d0bb50eeb> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x231d9000 - 0x232fdfff AddressBookUI armv7s  <6fe5557b059b3ff38179c43183cfe8c3> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x23495000 - 0x23708fff AudioToolbox armv7s  <5cf7594c3e8e33a889f26f9d2b8f74b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x23870000 - 0x239f7fff CFNetwork armv7s  <79b211df401f377fb05acc07a57db3ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x239f8000 - 0x23a78fff CloudKit armv7s  <aa1d623f3be434a6a75d2e49b41d26b6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit
0x23a79000 - 0x23ad8fff CoreAudio armv7s  <5b3129e5e3c23c4fb1052346c18e63b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x23af1000 - 0x23b0efff CoreBluetooth armv7s  <2040fbe8e91833e5a14c2e4961b5995b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x23b0f000 - 0x23d1afff CoreData armv7s  <db7e2287362438249bb753788c64a2b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x23d1b000 - 0x24047fff CoreFoundation armv7s  <a76fd43513ee3af9af444082a92ad639> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x24048000 - 0x24172fff CoreGraphics armv7s  <a3d08c6b246236fd9a078619f6c2010b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x241b2000 - 0x241b4fff libCGXType.A.dylib armv7s  <8c8f282d69573460983d78cbaebfd8cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x241b5000 - 0x241bffff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib armv7s  <795fcab613223b6d833937453beb1048> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x243a7000 - 0x243c2fff libRIP.A.dylib armv7s  <ae6bf33909b531b6abae4b007d9dd46b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x243c3000 - 0x244d1fff CoreImage armv7s  <0dd5152defdf3200b22c29876b05e34b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x244d2000 - 0x24529fff CoreLocation armv7s  <1153f2e6bde036f4b611833aa85dd9ac> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x2455b000 - 0x245f5fff CoreMedia armv7s  <b3e1c2a8262b38a697b5fd5478376e97> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x245f6000 - 0x246b6fff CoreMotion armv7s  <0e91543dde123205bbfb0eec336f82e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x246b7000 - 0x24715fff CoreTelephony armv7s  <32757860a7b23ee6b10cdfb2bcb5e5b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x24716000 - 0x247ddfff CoreText armv7s  <4be50da4f4d13b59b32ca55d4660e5c5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x247de000 - 0x247f3fff CoreVideo armv7s  <b1d41cec8ddc3c27be6f5459e17f1d2d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x247f4000 - 0x248e9fff EventKit armv7s  <af7bcad4baa7326eb020d805b49df854> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x24a5f000 - 0x24c61fff Foundation armv7s  <fadfe1d878803b27a0683288c1c7948b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x24c8e000 - 0x24cadfff GSS armv7s  <a384f737744b3e67be4b006612b27b58> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/GSS
0x24d41000 - 0x24d97fff IOKit armv7s  <df1bb671b5d5392cbb95b89ed6341e78> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x24d98000 - 0x24fd9fff ImageIO armv7s  <5cd6989e5626302aa49787b87e78ce32> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x24fda000 - 0x25328fff JavaScriptCore armv7s  <0041abdf36ff318981798e691a194dda> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x255fb000 - 0x25603fff MediaAccessibility armv7s  <5c1cbb4f664b3d049bc5c0ac98cb8a90> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x25604000 - 0x257ddfff MediaPlayer armv7s  <2fbb4a5dc62938f999bd72c93b9f5a50> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x257de000 - 0x25b55fff MediaToolbox armv7s  <47c440c3064b3b9194c8ffe6a096c37c> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x25c15000 - 0x25c81fff Metal armv7s  <2c1c274d748d330c81520ccdf07a8be1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x25c82000 - 0x25d11fff MobileCoreServices armv7s  <5e571169affe3b1f97863142d3438da5> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x26714000 - 0x267ebfff GLEngine armv7s  <18f54691165b3b1d9a63e4f76460d1e0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x267ec000 - 0x267f4fff OpenGLES armv7s  <b0df2c3e1d583413b2babe8e95a7e099> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x267f6000 - 0x267f6fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7s  <ab28723da4e234fd87a6e12dae52c3a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x267f7000 - 0x267f9fff libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7s  <f073564b5746376a945531dcb28ebdb9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x267fa000 - 0x267fdfff libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7s  <70abd418d5523929a02f9f22f834962e> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x267fe000 - 0x26806fff libGFXShared.dylib armv7s  <2cbde78e8e6c3d9da3a7271b053294bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x26807000 - 0x26849fff libGLImage.dylib armv7s  <a418f2754f373d3395a6aad59e50c371> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x2684a000 - 0x26985fff libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7s  <bef37dada4933217a952b1c362d5a6a3> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x26cd7000 - 0x26e29fff QuartzCore armv7s  <4a753d93b6033495b66178dd7535fd96> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x26e2a000 - 0x26e7dfff QuickLook armv7s  <593a3c45e1693456bfc917526490e399> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x2706c000 - 0x270acfff Security armv7s  <52c6a10cc12c33cda98ce09e002c6a35> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x27250000 - 0x272acfff SystemConfiguration armv7s  <0dfa14680b583dd2994e2cc0563ebd53> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x272af000 - 0x27b47fff UIKit armv7s  <5e0a38c7a0a33afc9e0e51edbdc2e8f3> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x27b48000 - 0x27baffff VideoToolbox armv7s  <d19c7c7e97533cde961652039bbcc310> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x27bb0000 - 0x27d95fff WebKit armv7s  <4e6d38f557ea3c2cb906c580d58723d5> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x28062000 - 0x28064fff AGXCompilerConnection armv7s  <21e8cec6e57c3dbe82e9ae4e21887fab> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AGXCompilerConnection.framework/AGXCompilerConnection
0x2806f000 - 0x2807afff AOSNotification armv7s  <30ac6892bcf1347383b6ca73b0c447be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/AOSNotification
0x281cf000 - 0x2821bfff AccountsDaemon armv7s  <440e21ee4a4e3ee9b1891b016268b59e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountsDaemon.framework/AccountsDaemon
0x2821c000 - 0x2823dfff AccountsUI armv7s  <a85ce8aa63ef349f90b9fbf16a040a6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountsUI.framework/AccountsUI
0x2823e000 - 0x28242fff AggregateDictionary armv7s  <7cb2e7f3daac30dbba7a9cf452850eb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x2840b000 - 0x28436fff AirPlaySupport armv7s  <10dd1721d0ac327f8f8714bb749de10a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirPlaySupport.framework/AirPlaySupport
0x28630000 - 0x2866efff AppSupport armv7s  <85ae995cc0083b8f861e9af66f426b8b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x2866f000 - 0x286b5fff AppleAccount armv7s  <c8d7c7cc33873ca184d666626d1e2e49> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x2879d000 - 0x287dafff AppleJPEG armv7s  <9d28d8b8c27e3b4d9af820fe71478279> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x287e5000 - 0x287f7fff ApplePushService armv7s  <9019b7f0259b32e2bf08eb9e3e61b315> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x287f8000 - 0x287fefff AppleSRP armv7s  <2bc7687cb4ea3b258e7412e03765e14c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP
0x28833000 - 0x2883cfff AssertionServices armv7s  <5a349cdba4e63bb6a4d15bb6ed3266af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x2883d000 - 0x28855fff AssetsLibraryServices armv7s  <7419fc839e043757a22253d762c0a6fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x28856000 - 0x2887afff AssistantServices armv7s  <c1333e5e6c663276bc90f9a951c01cf8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x288a9000 - 0x288adfff BTLEAudioController armv7s  <2dcdae1d597e3f0fbf940c6df8a8ef27> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
0x288ae000 - 0x288c5fff BackBoardServices armv7s  <ffee59ef60f9330a9bdb28d8741b1b02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x288c8000 - 0x288fdfff BaseBoard armv7s  <f0482a734fba3477bd24881eb35f8dbe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x288fe000 - 0x28904fff BluetoothManager armv7s  <fc99330ba35934c1b14610b4d86b7471> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x28905000 - 0x2892bfff Bom armv7s  <554f954a2ece30fbbb343a1ad991af68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x289f6000 - 0x28a1ffff CalendarFoundation armv7s  <6664e18ccf0d3b509037b2aa3e957b25> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CalendarFoundation.framework/CalendarFoundation
0x28b2b000 - 0x28b33fff CaptiveNetwork armv7s  <9a9f451fee273d698cb4497668b931a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x28b34000 - 0x28c56fff Celestial armv7s  <00f08339e5a53f9c954529a1f5b2e124> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x28c64000 - 0x28c7cfff CertInfo armv7s  <cae40259896d3df8a24ef147a5676ffb>
```

.
.
.

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report, otherwise nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but if your app is using coredata, could it be requesting too much space? Alternatively, could your app have a memory leak and thus uses up all the RAM? The later happens often when the app freezes for like 30 seconds before crashing, the os is releasing resources.